# AngularJS injection of http response

Tags: angularjs

I would appreciate any help in figuring out something about the code below. Specifically, how does Angular determine that it should inject the response of the resource request into  `authenticationResult`?

```
myApp.controller(...{

................ 

$scope.login = function() {

    UserService.authenticate($.param({username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}),   
                                             function(authenticationResult) {

        ...........

} );


var services = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);


services.factory('UserService', function($resource) {

return $resource('/restendpoint/:action', {},

    {

        authenticate: {

            method: 'POST',

            params: {'action' : 'authenticate'},

            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

        }

    }

);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how basic JavaScript works (usage of callbacks) and the way [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) is designed.

```
Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
```

Resource action takes the second and third parameters as `success` and `error` callback. [Go through the fine documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), things will be pretty much clear.

Want to understand JavaScript callback, [let me Google that for you](http://bit.ly/1wnmNrG). :) Or [some basic inputs.](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

Answer (score 0):

The way callbacks usually works is the following:

```
function fncall(bool, callback){
    var obj;
    if(typeof bool !== 'boolean')
        callback(new Error('A boolean is expected'));
    if(bool)
        obj = {value: true};
    else
        obj = {value: false} ;
    callback(null, obj);
};
```

and you use it like:

```
fncall(false, function(result){
    //using result... this is sync..
});
```

In this case would be more like and errorCallback and a successCallback.. but the behaviour is similar so remember for javascript everything is a value, so a function is a value too that's why you can pass it as a variable, this is the basic behaviour of callbacks.. obviously callbacks use to be used with async operations but not necessary..

saludos.